# Print en una sola linea sin eliminar el output Python3

Tags: python-3.x

antes que nada el código de ejemplo:

```
import time
print("Hola, esto es una prueba", end="\r")

for i in range(1000): 
    print(i, end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.50)
```

Como ven en el código estoy intentando imprimir todo en una sola línea, pero cuando lo intento hay un problema, que al imprimirse se sobrescribe, y no es eso lo que quiero que pase, sino que primero me imprima **"Hola, esto es una prueba"** y luego en la misma línea haga el conteo como ven en el código pero sin el Hola..., saben alguna manera que se pueda imprimir en una sola línea pero sin sobrescribirse y sin eliminar el output?
Este es el output que recibo:

```
10la, esto es una prueba
```

Y este es el que espero:

```
Hola, esto es una prueba
```

Y en la misma línea el conteo pero eliminando el Hola, esto es una prueba para que el conteo sea independiente.

Comment: Utiliza el módulo `sys`

Comment: para que si me puedes explicar, osea que debo hacer precisamente con ese modulo?

Comment: perdón me equivoqué. era el modulo `os`, ahora hago una respuesta

Comment: Vale, lo agradecería

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si he entendido lo que quieres. Entiendo que quieres la frase "Hola, esto es una prueba X" donde X sería 1,2,3,4.... todo en la misma línea.

Suponiendo que lo haya entendido bien, prueba así:

```
import time
texto = "Hola, esto es una prueba"
print(texto, end="\r")

for i in range(1000): 
    print(texto+' '+str(i), end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.50)
```

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es imprimir en una linea el Hola, esto es una prueba, y que luego en esa misma linea que haga como una limpieza del Hola, osea que lo borre del output pero sin eliminar el contenido anterior del output, solo que se elimine esa única linea para poder imprimir en la misma linea la secuencia de números

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una manera de hacerlo, les comparto el código:

```
  import time
  print("Hola, esto es una prueba", end="\r")
  time.sleep(2)
 
  for i in range(1000):
      print(f"{i}                           ", end="\r")
      time.sleep(0.50)
```

El espacio que esta al lado de la variable i es la clave ya que eso es lo que nos permite "limpiar" si se le puede llamar así, aun así no lo recomiendo ya que si tenemos una cadena mas larga tendríamos que poner mas espacio y no es bueno ver mucho espacio en el código, si alguien tiene una mejor forma que lo diga, se agradecería...

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es borrar el resultado anterior y solo obtener como resultado final los número, podemos apoyarnos del módulo `os` que nos permite hacer funciones del sistema operativo, junto a su método `system()` podemos ejecutar comandos que serán interpretados por la terminal.

```py
import time
import os

print("Hola, esto es una prueba")
os.system("clear")

for i in range(1000): 
    print(i, end=" ")
    time.sleep(0.50)
```

El comando que le pases va a variar del sistema operativo que uses, si no te funciona puedes usar el comando `cls` o para facilitar la tarea utilizar una lambda

```py
...

clear= lambda: os.system('cls' if os.name in ('nt', 'dos') else 'clear')

print("Hola, esto es una prueba")
clear()

...
```

Otra forma es simulando esto, imprimiendo varias lineas.

```py
import time
print("Hola, esto es una prueba", end="\r")
print("\n"*150) #imprimimos 150 saltos de linea
for i in range(1000): 
    print(i, end="\r")
    time.sleep(0.50)
```